# Erro de Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi

Toda vez que eu estou usando o *Delphi 6* e mexo em algum formulário ligado a um banco de dados, quando vou executar o programa que compilei, ele reclama que o banco de dados está sendo usado no momento. Quando eu fecho a *IDE* do *Delphi*, o programa funciona normalmente, o que será que está acontecendo?

[image: Print do Erro]

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema bem corriqueiro no `BDE`, para isso vá no BDEadmin e va na aba

- *Configuration -> System-> Init no campo SHAREDMEMSIZE coloque 4096 de
  apply*

Comment: Valeu, amigo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!